# How can I lock my Ubuntu phone using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, phone, screensaver

I have the terminal installed on my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu phone, is there a command I can use to lock the phone from the terminal?

By "lock" I mean the same thing that the lock button on top of the phone does.

I need to know how to do this to make a .desktop file shortcut to lock the phone without pressing the physical button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no such functionality. It may be added if you file a feature request.
You can make a feature suggest by submitting it as a "bug" at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu .

Mark the bug with the tag [Wishlist] and the developers will know there is a demand. Only the maintainer of a project or bug superviser can then change the "Importance" to "Wishlist".

The link to actually file a bug "Report a bug" in the top right corner leads to a page, where the possibility to file a bug is hard to find. The link can be found in the section:

> 3. Tips and tricks: [Filing bugs at Launchpad.net](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_at_Launchpad.net)

It is also possible to file a bug now at the console if you type

```
ubuntu-bug
```

into the console and follow the instructions.

Comment: I filed bug reports with the "wishlist" tag.  [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1492475) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1492477) Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you could do it. The formatting in my answer doesn't seem to work. Also i'll be glad if you could mark this question as solved.